# Getting links to open in a new tab

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to have this as a feature request? Find it annoying to have to right click to open a link in a new tab. Is it possible to have all links set to `"target=blank"`?

Comment: You should use Ctrl + Click or the mouse wheel click.

Comment: I know I can do this but 10/10 times I click on a link I dont want it opening on the same page. Why Ctrl + Click if they can just set it to do that?

Comment: What about people that want to open the link in the same page? :D

Comment: lol...I see where you are going with this. It's a pet peeve and was wondering if it was a shared- annoyance

Comment: :D I'm in the same case. I always open links in new tabs. But I'm so used to the mouse wheel click that I don't even think about it anymore.

Comment: I dream of a better world where we dont have to "crtl + click" to open a link in a new tab

Comment: I dream of a better world full of developers :D

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think the question is more about the internal behaviour of the stackexchange. Not the link posted in answer and comments.

Comment: @MartinLezer Perhaps. The way I see it they are asking for the same feature (open in new tab), just different implementations of it. I think it brings more visibility to our need for this feature that it has been asked for more than once.